# Cannot get context element text

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is pretty straight forward but I caannit get the expected result. I want to iterate over a set of **paragraph** elements and get their text node using `.each()` function although I get the entire document text nodes.

Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <main>
   <p>Kon</p>
   <p>Mule</p>
  </main>
  <p>Hello riko</p>
  <h2 hidden data-modal-target=".modal-progress">Header 2</h2>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
   // console.log($("p"))
   $("p").each((index)=> {
    console.log( $( this ).text())
    // console.log(index)
   })
  })
 </script>
</html>
```

Instead of getting:

> Kon
>
> Mule
>
> Hello Riko

I get this:

```
            Kon
            Mule

        Hello riko
        Header 2


        $(function () {
            // console.log($("p"))
            $("p").each((index)=> {
                console.log( $( this ).text() + index)
                // console.log(index)
            })
        })
```

three times.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: replace `(index)=>` with `function(index)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is not accessible in [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). You need to use regular functions to do that:

```js
$("p").each(function(index) {
  console.log($(this).text())
  // console.log(index)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <p>Kon</p>
  <p>Mule</p>
</main>
<p>Hello riko</p>
<h2 hidden data-modal-target=".modal-progress">Header 2</h2>
```

Or you need to get the native JS array from the jQuery collection using [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and use `forEach()` on it:

```
$("p").get().forEach((item) => {
  console.log($(item).text())
})
```

Comment: `$("p").each((index, elem) => {
  console.log($(elem).text())
})` would also work

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything correct as per code. Something is wrong with your environment. here is working code 
https://jsfiddle.net/RanjeetKumarGautam/w6ojokp1/

```
$(function () {
            // console.log($("p"))
            $("p").each((index)=> {
                console.log( $( this ).text())
                // console.log(index)
            })
        })
```